# how do I card shuffle a pandas series quickly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

suppose I have the `pd.Series`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.arange(10), list('abcdefghij'))
```

I'd like to "shuffle" this series like a deck of cards by interweaving the top half with the bottom half.

I'd expect results like this

```
a    0
f    5
b    1
g    6
c    2
h    7
d    3
i    8
e    4
j    9
dtype: int32
```

---

***Conclusions***
final function

```
def perfect_shuffle(s):
    n = s.values.shape[0]  # get length of s
    l = (n + 1) // 2 * 2   # get next even number after n
    # use even number to reshape and only use n of them after ravel
    a = np.arange(l).reshape(2, -1).T.ravel()[:n]
    # construct new series slicing both values and index
    return pd.Series(s.values[a], s.index.values[a])
```

***demonstration***

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(11), list('abcdefghijk'))
print(perfect_shuffle(s))

a     0
g     6
b     1
h     7
c     2
i     8
d     3
j     9
e     4
k    10
f     5
dtype: int64
```

---

***`order='F'` vs `T`***
I had suggested using `T.ravel()` as opposed to `ravel(order='F')`
After investigation, it hardly matters but `ravel(order='F')` is better for larger arrays.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(dict(T=[], R=[]))

for n in np.power(10, np.arange(1, 8)):
    a = np.arange(n).reshape(2, -1)
    stamp = pd.datetime.now()
    for _ in range(100):
        a.ravel(order='F')
    d.loc[n, 'R'] = (pd.datetime.now() - stamp).total_seconds()
    stamp = pd.datetime.now()
    for _ in range(100):
        a.T.ravel()
    d.loc[n, 'T'] = (pd.datetime.now() - stamp).total_seconds()

d
```

[image]

```
d.plot()
```

[image]

---

*Thanks **unutbu** and **Warren Weckesser***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In then special case where the length of the Series is even, you can to do a [perfectly shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_shuffle) by reshaping its values into two rows and then using [`ravel(order='F')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to read the items off in Fortran order:

```
In [12]: pd.Series(s.values.reshape(2,-1).ravel(order='F'), s.index)
Out[12]: 
a    0
b    5
c    1
d    6
e    2
f    7
g    3
h    8
i    4
j    9
dtype: int64
```

Fortran order makes the left-most axis increment fastest. So in a 2D array the
values are read off by going down the rows of one column before progressing to
the next column. This has the effect of interleaving the values, compared to the
usual C-order.

---

In the general case where the length of the Series could be odd, 
perhaps the fastest way is to reassign the values using shifted slices:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def perfect_shuffle(ser):
    arr = ser.values
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    N = (len(arr)+1)//2
    result[::2] = arr[:N]
    result[1::2] = arr[N:]
    result = pd.Series(result, index=ser.index)
    return result

s = pd.Series(np.arange(11), list('abcdefghijk'))
print(perfect_shuffle(s))
```

yields

```
a     0
b     6
c     1
d     7
e     2
f     8
g     3
h     9
i     4
j    10
k     5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Brilliant. You really cut the Gordian Knot here.

Comment: I'd use reshape(2, -1).T.flatten()

Comment: The answer was accepted, so I guess it isn't a problem, but this method won't work if the length of the series is odd.

Comment: In the case of an odd, the last element will be last, just perform this task on the series sans the last element and append.

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. For better performance though, it's usually better to allocate the right amount of space first, and fill the container than it is to use append.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @unutbu's answer, some benchmarks:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> setup = '''
... import pandas as pd
... import numpy as np
... s = pd.Series(list('abcdefghij'), np.arange(10))
... '''
>>> 
>>> funcs = ['s[np.random.permutation(s.index)]', "pd.Series(s.values.reshape(2,-1).ravel(order='F'), s.index)",
...             's.iloc[np.random.permutation(s.index)]', "s.values.reshape(-1, 2, order='F').ravel()"]
>>> 
>>> for f in funcs:
...     print(f)
...     print(min(timeit.Timer(f, setup).repeat(3, 50)))
... 
s[np.random.permutation(s.index)]
0.029795593000017107
pd.Series(s.values.reshape(2,-1).ravel(order='F'), s.index)
0.0035402200010139495
s.iloc[np.random.permutation(s.index)]
0.010904800990829244
s.values.reshape(-1, 2, order='F').ravel()
0.00019640100072138011
```

The final `f` in `funcs` is > 99% faster than the first `np.random.permutation` approach, so that's probably your best bet.